# Angularjs ui-router controller access resolve property, unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The plunk link is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uquwtuPcwZMPFJPBKBBY?p=preview

In short, the interesting part:

```
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('root');
$stateProvider.state('root', {
  url: '',
  template: '<div>Hello {{greetMe}}</div>',
  resovle: {
    person: function() {
      return {
        value: 'simple!'
      };
    },
  },
  controller: ['$scope', 'person',
    function($scope, person) {
      $scope.greetMe = 'World';
    }
  ]
});
}]);
```

If I remove 'person' dependency from the controller, everything works. but then there would be no point in using resolve. Any pointers on how to fix this to access 'person'?

Comment: It apprears that this question can no longer be reproduced or **was caused by a simple typographical error**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled 'resolve' wrong:

```
resovle: {
```

Should be:

```
resolve: {
```

Corrected plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gTOSMQyGDnPooD3F5aO9?p=preview

Comment: thanks, it was kinda embarrassing to say that this issue cost me 4 hours